# Xcode 4.3.2 show hidden files

Tags: xcode, file, hidden, finder

I am using Xcode 4.3.2 and I am trying to add some SDK references to my project. 
I can SEE the files using Finder, as I used the terminal script to view hidden files. 
Yet, when I go to my user home directory in Xcode finder, it does not show the "hidden" 'Library' folder under my user profile that stores my SDK files.

*Scratching head*

Answer (score 24):

Press and hold the <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd>  and <kbd>.</kbd>  keys at the same time.

Then you can switch to view hidden/non-hidden files.

Answer (score 13):

Answering you 9 months later from OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion...

Press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> from within Xcode's Open dialog -- this is the Go To Folder command from Finder. This works in XCode's Open dialog as well. You could go to 'Library' or, as I did below, go to the otherwise hidden .config directory by typing '.config'

[This screenshot](https://www.flickr.com/photos/_complex_/8499908883/) shows both the process & the result of opening the .config folder. Note that I've already 'gone' to the .config folder once, which is why it's displayed on the left, above Applications.

Comment: You can also press the slash '/' key to open the *Go to the Folder* dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Which command are you Using ?
Use Bellow Command it worked for me.

If the Library folder is not visible in your  folder, enter the command "chflags nohidden ~/Library/ " on Terminal(Applications->Utilities->Terminal) application

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem (but arrived on this page looking for answers).

I removed a reference to a file in XCode which I actually wanted to keep but the file still existed in finder.

Even though the file is in the correct folder, Xcode won't acknowledge it until you re-add it via **File > Add Files To "YourProject"**

The point I'm making is that the files in your code project folders vs. those actually included in the XCode project are two different things